# Run command to disable a plugin in modeline

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

System: gvim 8.1 1-116 / windows10

A file that I'd like to use modeline (enabled): `# vim: ft=python` but disable `ale` plugin that will trigger `on save` - the file contains some python codes.

Command that I'd like to run by vim before parse the file: `:ALEDisable`.

Here I just want to disbale ALE on a specific file that comes with clear declaration in modeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already solved your problem, but for the benefit of future readers, I'll paste a couple of bits from `:help modeline`:

> No other commands than "set" are supported, for security reasons (somebody
>   might create a Trojan horse text file with modelines).
>
> [...]
>
> Hint: If you would like to do something else than setting an option, you could define an autocommand that checks the file for a specific string.  For
>   example:
>
> ```
> au BufReadPost * if getline(1) =~ "VAR" | call SetVar() | endif
> ```
>
> And define a function SetVar() that does something with the line containing
>   "VAR".

Similarly, you could use something like:

```
au BufReadPost your_file.conf AleDisable
```

Or you could remove the modeline altogether with an autocommand along the lines of:

```
au BufReadPost your_file.conf AleDisable | set ft=python
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I just want to have highlight of `python` while keep `ft=conf` because this is a note that contains python code, I'd like to have `python` code highlighted properly, so just set modeline: `# vim: syntax=python` I can achieve the purpose.